# Remove duplicate values from an object array after using an .each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have an `each` function that takes the `td` elements of an html `table` and places them in an object array. My problem is that I only need the unique values from the table. This is causing my array to have duplicate values. ideally I would like to see unique values for `Product` and `valProduct`. `valProduct` is essentially the same as "Product`. Here is my closes attempt:

```js
var array_return = [];

$(".table__product td:nth-child(1)").each(function() {
  array_return.push({
    "Product": $(this).html(),
    "valProduct": $(this).html()
  });
});


array_return.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.Product - b.Product;
});

// delete all duplicates from the array_return
for (var i = 0; i < array_return.length - 1; i++) {
  if (array_return[i].Product == array_return[i + 1].Product) {
    delete array_return[i];
  }
}

// remove the "undefined entries"
array_return = array_return.filter(function(el) {
  return (typeof el !== "undefined");
});

alert(JSON.stringify(array_return));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/core.js"></script>


<table class="table__product">
  <tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>3384</td>
    <td>iPhone</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Samsung</td>
    <td>8800</td>
    <td>Galaxy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>LG</td>
    <td>8684</td>
    <td>V20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Google</td>
    <td>8179</td>
    <td>Pixel</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Blackberry</td>
    <td>4554</td>
    <td>Storm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Motorolla</td>
    <td>6764</td>
    <td>Z force</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>LEASING_REVENUE</td>
    <td NOWRAP align=RIGHT>-2100000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>LEASING_REVENUE</td>
    <td NOWRAP align=RIGHT>-2095011</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>LEASING_REVENUE</td>
    <td NOWRAP align=RIGHT>-2095010</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ECS/ACH</td>
    <td align=RIGHT>4493</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ECS/ACH</td>
    <td align=RIGHT>4494</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ECS/ACH</td>
    <td align=RIGHT>4495</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What is it doing or not doing that you need to change?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I removed the tag it was clearly out of place

Comment: Post your desired output from this example.

Comment: The above code is not properly removing duplicates from the array. If you put this code in jsfiddle you will see.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Duplicates from JavaScript Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused because of two things:

1. The value of the sorted array is not assigned back to anywhere
2. You are modifying the array by deleting keys in the `for` loop

What you need to do is define a new array in the `for` loop instead of modifying the original one, and then assign the new one to the original.

See the following code for an example:

```js
var array_return = [];
var filtered_array = [];
var filtered_array_keys = [];

$(".table__product td:nth-child(1)").each(function() {
  array_return.push({
    "Product": $(this).html(),
    "valProduct": $(this).html()
  });
});

// delete all duplicates from the array_return
for (var i = 0; i < array_return.length - 1; i++) {
  if (filtered_array_keys.indexOf(array_return[i].Product) < 0) {
    filtered_array_keys.push(array_return[i].Product);
    filtered_array.push(array_return[i]);
  }
}
array_return = filtered_array;

// remove the "undefined entries"
array_return = array_return.filter(function(el) {
  return (typeof el !== "undefined");
});

alert(JSON.stringify(array_return));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<table class="table__product">
  <tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>3384</td>
    <td>iPhone</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Samsung</td>
    <td>8800</td>
    <td>Galaxy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>LG</td>
    <td>8684</td>
    <td>V20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Google</td>
    <td>8179</td>
    <td>Pixel</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Blackberry</td>
    <td>4554</td>
    <td>Storm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Motorolla</td>
    <td>6764</td>
    <td>Z force</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>LEASING_REVENUE</td>
    <td NOWRAP align=RIGHT>-2100000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>LEASING_REVENUE</td>
    <td NOWRAP align=RIGHT>-2095011</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>LEASING_REVENUE</td>
    <td NOWRAP align=RIGHT>-2095010</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ECS/ACH</td>
    <td align=RIGHT>4493</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ECS/ACH</td>
    <td align=RIGHT>4494</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ECS/ACH</td>
    <td align=RIGHT>4495</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: "two things: 1)..." ?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Sorry the answer was posted by mistake will composing, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be better off copying the unique items to a new array rather than using the loop you are using. The problem with this part of the code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array_return.length - 1; i++) {
  if (array_return[i].Product == array_return[i + 1].Product) {
    delete array_return[i];
  }
}
```

is that:
1) when you delete an item from the array (say item at index 3). The item at index 4 becomes item 3 but then when you increment i in the loop, it will be checking index 4 (which used to be index 5) and index 4 never gets checked. I'd rewrite that to something like:

```
var newArray = [];   
newArray.push(array_return[0]); 
for (var i = 1; i < array_return.length; i++) {
      if (array_return[i].Product != array_return[i - 1].Product) {
        newArray.push(array_return[i]);
      }
    }
array_return = newArray;
```

I don't guarantee the syntax is perfect but this is definitely the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
var array_return = [];

$(".table__product td:nth-child(1)").each(function() {
  var value = $(this).html();

  // check if a product with value is already exist
  var exist = array_return.find(function(e){
      return e.Product == value;
  });
  // if exist, don't save
  if(exist) return;

  // else push it
  array_return.push({
    "Product": value,
    "valProduct": value
  });
});

// no need for more filtering.
```